# How to avoid the scrollbar in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a div of width 533px, inside the div i have svg element with same width to hold some rect element.

```
<div style="left: 47px; top: 479px; width: 533px; height: 56px; position:  absolute;>

<svg style=" width: 533px; height: 56px;>
 .... 
 // Some rect Element inside the svg
</svg>

<div>
```

The width of the rect is higher than the svg element, so i have clipped the rect using clippath. Now the rect potion outide the svg is not visible. but the horizontal scrollbar get enabled upto the rect width in window. This happen only in IE. In other browsers its working fine.

How to fix this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: document.getElementById("myDiv").style.overflow = "hidden";

Answer (score 0):

it's your browser compatibility issue, you must update your browser or you can use

```
<style>overflow:hidden;</style>
```

write this code in your header or in your main css..
hope it will work